# IONIC App crashes after Splash Screen

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic App which needs to be exported as Universal Windows App.

1. App works fine when served with browser. (ionic serve)
2. UWP Build generates successfully for Visual Studio. (ionic cordova build windows)
3. Running from Visual Studio on Local PC -> App Works fine. (Good Speed)
4. Running from Visual Studio on Windows 10 Phone -> App Works fine
   (Very Slow)
5. Running the App again on Windows Phone from Apps Drawer on Phone -> App Crashes after Cordova Splash Screen.

Possible Issue: App Might be taking too much memory.
Platform: IONIC 3

42 Entry Components are added. (All Pages) This may NOT be the correct way of doing it.

App used to work when Entry Components were 10 in number. App was Fast too.

Can we ditch non-starting pages from Entry components to save memory?